# Phpmysql show something if it exist in other table

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables
1.is user
2. Is content
3. Is option

So I just want to show all content with inner join with user table
Show (user + content)
But i just want to add some value condition by option table with (content id) must be match with (option id) too. So if it match it must be show 1, or if not it show 0.

(user + content) if option have some row id match with content id must be show 1 in content row

All the content must be show with user and content but just add a row condition in option table.

(Content + user) 1 or 0 if content id is matched id in option table

Basically we can check by add content id by use where to all row but I just want a faster way. so it have some way?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to follow, but I think you want a flag based on the `options` table after joining `users` and `content`.

If so, you can use `exists`:

```
select . . .,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from options o
                          where o.content_id = c.content_id and o.option = 1
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from users u join
     content c
     on . . .
```